# How to play torrented windows games on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine, intel-graphics, bittorrent, lutris

I Have been planning to completely to switch over ubuntu but I couldn't find any forum which gives step by step process to do so, I have no problem in playing steam games with help of proton but I couldn't find a way to play torrented games please help I know it could be done by lutris  but I couldn't find the option to select .exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stream to play Games available on Stream.
If You want to play windows games on your Linux machine Install Wine(https://www.winehq.org/about) and install your app on wine.